# Command already defined (custom command)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, counters

When compiling following code, I the compiler tells me that a command is already defined (the name is `\c@b...`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\piepart}[5]
{
    \draw[thick,fill=#4] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

    \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
    \let\midangle\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\trunc}{\midangle}
    \ifthenelse{\trunc < 90}{
    \draw (\midangle:1) node[above right]{#3};
    }
    {
        \ifthenelse{\trunc < 180}{
        \draw (\midangle:1) node[above left]{#3};
        }
        {
            \ifthenelse{\trunc < 270}{
            \draw (\midangle:1) node[below left]{#3};
            }
            {
                \draw (\midangle:1) node[below right]{#3};
            }
        }
    }
    \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
    \let\temp\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
    \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
    \node at (\midangle:0.8) {#5};

}

\newcommand{\piechart}[1]
{
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\foreach \p/\mcolor/\mname in #1
    {
        \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
        \addtocounter{b}{\p}
        \piepart{\thea/100*360}
                    {\theb/100*360}
                    {\mname}{\mcolor}{\p\%}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
\piechart{{75/gray/A, 18/green/B, 7/red/C}}                 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
\piechart{{75/gray/A, 18/green/B, 7/red/C}}                 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If somebody knows what creates the error, or how to solve it, could they please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Thank you for providing the example! Can you put into your post exactly what the error message is? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

There are two `\newcounter` calls inside the macro `\pichart`.
When the macro is called the second time, then the counters are already defined and you get the error messages about already defined commands `\c@a` and `\c@b`, which are the internal command representation of the counters.

Move the `\newcounter` calls outside and reset the counters inside the macro:

```
\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\newcommand*{\piechart}[1]{%
  \setcounter{a}{0}%
  \setcounter{b}{0}%
  ...
}
```

Full example for completeness (and with larger fonts):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\piepart}[5]
{
    \draw[thick,fill=#4] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

    \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
    \let\midangle\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\trunc}{\midangle}
    \ifthenelse{\trunc < 90}{
    \draw (\midangle:1) node[above right]{#3};
    }
    {
        \ifthenelse{\trunc < 180}{
        \draw (\midangle:1) node[above left]{#3};
        }
        {
            \ifthenelse{\trunc < 270}{
            \draw (\midangle:1) node[below left]{#3};
            }
            {
                \draw (\midangle:1) node[below right]{#3};
            }
        }
    }
    \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
    \let\temp\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
    \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
    \node at (\midangle:0.8) {#5};

}

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\newcommand{\piechart}[1]
{
    \setcounter{a}{0}%
    \setcounter{b}{0}%
    \foreach \p/\mcolor/\mname in #1
    {
        \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
        \addtocounter{b}{\p}
        \piepart{\thea/100*360}
                    {\theb/100*360}
                    {\mname}{\mcolor}{\p\%}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]
    \piechart{{75/gray/A, 18/green/B, 7/red/C}}                 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]
    \piechart{{75/gray/A, 18/green/B, 7/red/C}}                 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]